# how to do multiple search for data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, ms-access, search, gridview

```
Private Sub cmdsearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsearch.Click

Me.StockDataBindingSource.Filter = "ItemCode, ItemType, Quantity,CompanyDeliveredBy,ReceivedByPrintName,TotalCost   = '" & Me.txtsearch.Text & "'"

End Sub
```

I want to search more then one field in my database.

Comment: Don't really get your question. You want to get results from more than one column/table in a database?

Comment: Yeah i've got six columns in my girdview form that displays data i.e. itemcode, itemtype etc i can search only one of the columns i.e. itemtype displays the results but am wanting to search all the columns in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to specify the columns and tables you are referencing. If you have more than one table you might need to look into SQL joins http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Else,

```
SELECT column_one, column_two FROM columnname WHERE column_id ='1'
```

The example below uses SQLite to get data from the table **base_user** and it returns multiple columns i.e. firstname, lastname, username, etc. It is also parameterized to better secure your queries.

```
sqlText = "SELECT id AS userID, " & _
"first_name AS firstName, " & _
"last_name AS lastName, " & _
"user_name AS userName, " & _
"is_deleted AS isDeleted, " & _
"is_active AS isActive " & _
"FROM base_user WHERE " & _
"is_deleted=@isDeleted AND " & _
"is_active=@isActive"
SetDBCommand(sqlText)
DBCommandSQLite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isActive", IsActive)
DBCommandSQLite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isDeleted", IsDeleted)
```

Comment: But am not using SQL. Am using access connecting it through a windows form (VB.net) and displaying the data in a girdview, am developing a desktop application.